# T-SQL. How to select Item[i] and Item[i-1] into same row WITHOUT cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table without identity field. the structure about:

```
Date date,
SomeFK int,
Key float,
Value float
```

I need to be able to select not using cursor something like

```
select Key, PrevKey, Value from ... where Key > @a and Key <= @b
```

where the PrevKey has to be a Key from previous record, given that the recordset ordered by Key

If data like this:

```
0.1, 2.0
0.2, 3.0
0.3, 5.0
0.4, 4.0
```

Then expected result for @a=0.15 and @b=0.3

```
0.2, 0.1, 3.0
0.3, 0.2, 5.0
```

**What I am trying to do is to calculate a formula: SUM(Value[i] * (Key[i] - Key[i-1]))**

Comment: SQL2008.. I need it to be fast as the data can be very big..

Comment: What is the primary key on that table?? (seeing you say you don't have an identity)

Comment: Date + FK + Key... tottaly unhelpful in this case

Comment: ~~~ However, you can create a temp table with identity col... Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you could try is this CTE approach:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ([Key] FLOAT PRIMARY KEY, Value FLOAT)
INSERT @Data VALUES(0.1, 2.0),(0.2, 3.0), (0.3, 5.0), (0.4,4.0)

;WITH CTEData AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Key]) AS RowNo,
    [Key], Value
FROM @Data
)

SELECT d1.[Key], d2.[Key] AS PreviousKey, d1.Value
FROM CTEData d1
    INNER JOIN CTEData d2 ON d1.RowNo-1 = d2.RowNo
```

**Edit**
Just seen that your PK is not exclusively on "Key", which the above example assumes.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I need some time to test it as the real table and conditions are more complex...

Comment: Dont worry. The KEY has to be unique by nature. Is not enforced though but I dont mind it to fail - will help to detect incorrect data.